# C++, C++/CLI,C#, WPF TDD, mocking

Tags: software-testing, unit-tests, mocks

I'm new to TDD and BDD, My system flow is as following.

1. WPF/C# MVVM layer with a button (don't really have only one) to open an image and run the image in an image processing pipeline.
2. C++/CLI layer which calls Run(image img) function.
3. C++ ImageProcessing engine which calculates the new image output according to the input variables and returns the image all the way up to layer 1. for the viewer.

I would like to create mock/stub objects for all of the parts in my system, I know MS visual studio testing supports unit tests for both c++ and C#.

Do I have to build my own stubs manually, or is there a better approach/mocking frameowork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My team and I work with [Typemock](https://www.typemock.com/). It's a unit testing framework for C# and they also have a mocking framework for C++. We are very satisfied with this product, I highly recommend using it.